# Как убрать прогресс бар

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

Мне нужно убрать прогресс бар из refreshlayout та или сделать невидимым.
Как растянуть и отпускать layout и обработать refresh без прогресс бара?

**Пример:**

[image]

Comment: дела в том что прогресс бар внутри refreshlayout та, я не знаю как найти и отключить visible

Comment: Добавь xml код твоего layoutа.

Comment: вот ссылка (https://github.com/baoyongzhang/android-PullRefreshLayout) который я использую, там я не нашел как убрать прогресс бар.

Answer (score 0):

выключить

```
 SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

включить

```
SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

Comment: я не хочу отключить refreshlayout. я хочу убрать прогресс бар или сделать невидимым

Comment: @ЖавохЭргашев ЛОЛ))Так его используют false сделать невидимым, а  true сделать видимым)